# PL/SQL Packages inserting count Number autmomatically in variable

Tags: oracle, variables, plsql, count, package

the Exercise is:

Create a public variable in a package called v_Guest_Count
that is automatically initialised with the number of 
Guests in the Guests table.  Use the following SQL:
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   Guests;

I tried it like this but it won't work:

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY BEACHCOMBER IS
v_guest_count NUMBER;

BEGIN
SELECT COUNT (*) FROM A2_GUESTS
INTO v_guest_count;
END BEACHCOMBER;
```

Thank you

Edit: This is the testing code:

```
PROMPT 
PROMPT TESTING: Initialisation of the v_Guest_Count variable.  Expect 81.
BEGIN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('v_Guest_Count has been initialised to: '||TO_CHAR(BEACHCOMBER.v_Guest_Count));
END;
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have A LOT of stuff wrong with your PL/SQL.  I have modified the code below.

1. If you want to return a scalar result from a query, you either need an OUT parameter on the procedure, or create a function to return the value.
2. Syntax for "select into" is wrong.
3. You cannot access the value of a locally-scoped variable (v_guest_count) outside of the function/procedure.

```
create or replace FUNCTION BEACHCOMBER_COUNT
    RETURN NUMBER
    IS
    v_guest_count NUMBER;
```

`BEGIN
   SELECT COUNT (*)  INTO v_guest_count
   FROM dual; -- A2_GUESTS;
   RETURN v_guest_count;
END;

    PROMPT PROMPT TESTING: Initialisation of the v_Guest_Count variable.  Expect 81.
    BEGIN
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('v_Guest_Count has been initialised to: '||TO_CHAR(BEACHCOMBER_COUNT()));
    END;
    /`

I would suggest getting a good pl/sql book.

Comment: whilst this does get the result, that does not answer the actual query need, the testing query cannot be changed, so it needs to be a public variable within a package that is the result of the select statement...